# What can I do about this painted concrete?

Tags: concrete, paint, outdoor

The previous owners of my home decided to paint the sidewalk and porch surfaces.  Not only are they painted but they are this horrible color.  Do you have any suggestions on what to repaint them with or any other cost efficient coating options for them?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if 'gray' is all that horrible, but that's a matter of opinion. If the paint is adhered well, you can simply clean, prime, and apply a new coat. You'll want to use paint specially made for foot traffic and outdoor use.

Answer (score 2):

On the plus side, its a (seemingly) well adhered horrible color.  That means recoating it another color, will be a fruitful effort.

Buy the best coating you can afford. Horizontal, exterior surfaces receive the harshest  conditions.  An anti-slip additive will be money well spent.

Answer (score 0):

Paint on horizontal surfaces is not a good idea.

My professional viewpoint is grind it off and get a professional to apply covercrete/spray pave (cementitious material) that will not peel & will seal concrete properly and won't be slippery underfoot.

Comment: For any self promotion, place it in your user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try a decent pressure washer for removal. Job done.

Comment: With a good quality concrete paint even a 5000 psi pressure washer won't strip off ( I don't know if this was 2 part or single). I had to "shot blast" a slab that the owners wanted cleaned as the epoxy did not budge with the pressure washer, where there were chips in the epoxy the pressure washer would cut into the concrete but not cut the paint. The shot blaster cleaned it off but that was an expensive clean off.